# get child model of user in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Player model that is a one to one field of User:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="player")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

If I have a User instance in the template:

```
{{ user }}
```

Am I able to get the related Player?  If so, how?

I tried:

```
{{ user.player.first_name }}
```

but it didn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
{{ user.player }}
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

Make sure you have a related `Player` instance.

Comment: @Atma I edited the answer, make you you have a Player object related to this User.